# Kubernetes node breaks on restarting containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

After upgrading to the latest docker (18.09.0) and kubernetes (1.12.2) my Kubernetes node breaks on deploying security updates that restart `containerd`.

I have: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "live-restore": true
}
```

This was sufficient to allow docker restart in the past without restarting pods.

Kubelet is started as:

```
/usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --network-plugin=cni --fail-swap-on=false --feature-gates=PodPriority=true
```

Now, restarting `containerd` will preserves the old pods, but also recreates them under the fresh `containerd` process.

Initial situation, before restart:

```
/usr/bin/containerd
/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
 \_ containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level info
     \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/1a36f40f3c3531d13b8bc493049a1900662822e01e2c911f8
     |   \_ /usr/bin/dumb-init /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader 
     |       \_ /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader --ingress-class
     |           \_ /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader --ingress-class=nginx-php --configma
     |               \_ nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
     |                   \_ nginx: worker process
     |                   \_ nginx: worker process
     \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c9a82204115c50788d132aa6c11735d90412dacb48a219d31
     |   \_ /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
     \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/3004e3fa5f7e2b45865c6cc33abb884d9140af16f2594a11d
     |   \_ /sbin/runsvdir -P /etc/service/enabled
     |       \_ runsv bird
     |       |   \_ bird -R -s /var/run/calico/bird.ctl -d -c /etc/calico/confd/config/bird.cfg
     |       \_ runsv bird6
     |       |   \_ bird6 -R -s /var/run/calico/bird6.ctl -d -c /etc/calico/confd/config/bird6.cfg
     |       \_ runsv confd
     |       |   \_ calico-node -confd
     |       \_ runsv felix
     |           \_ calico-node -felix
     \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/1f3c48e28c7fde2f67c40d5641abfa9a29e3dfcbc436321f6
     |   \_ /bin/sh /install-cni.sh
     |       \_ sleep 10
     \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/8371571ce29be4959951cf8ad70e57aa1f4a146f5ca43435b
         \_ /coredns -conf /etc/coredns/Corefile
```

After restarting containerd/docker, those old containers aren't found, and they are all recreated under the fresh `containerd` process. This gives duplicate processes for all pods!

It looks like containerd completely forget about the old containers, because `killall containerd-shim`, won't just kill those old pods, but simply reparent the children under init:

```
/usr/bin/dumb-init /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader --ingress-cl
 \_ /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader --ingress-class=nginx-php -
     \_ /nginx-ingress-controller --default-backend-service=infra/old-nginx-php --election-id=ingress-controller-leader --ingress-class=nginx-php --configmap=infra/phpi
         \_ nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
             \_ nginx: worker process
             \_ nginx: worker process
/usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
/sbin/runsvdir -P /etc/service/enabled
 \_ bird -R -s /var/run/calico/bird.ctl -d -c /etc/calico/confd/config/bird.cfg
 \_ bird6 -R -s /var/run/calico/bird6.ctl -d -c /etc/calico/confd/config/bird6.cfg
/bin/sh /install-cni.sh
 \_ sleep 10
```

Obviously, having old calico and nginx still hanging around keeps hostports in use, so the new pods don't start and the node becomes completely unusable. Manually killing all old processes or rebooting seems to only option.

Is there some new setting required to make sure kubelet finds those old `containerd` instances? Or does this happen because there is a global `containerd` and version started by docker?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue yesterday and after containerd restart, I couldn't able to exec into my running pods as well. The issue is with docker itself.

Once the containerd restart, the docker daemon still try to process event streams against the old socket handles. After that, the error handeling when client can't connect to the containerd leads to the CPU spike on machine.

The only way to recover from this situation is to docker restart (systemctl restart docker).

The issue is fixed with the following ticket:

https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36173

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'm already running docker 18.09.0, yet this issue occurs. Maybe it's something else in my situation.